# Is it an abstract class or a pure virtual (interface)?

Tags: c++, oop

It might be a silly question but I never saw a question about it or read about it.

Imagine that we have this:

```
class Numeric
{
public:
    virtual ~Numeric() {}
    virtual int getNumeric() const = 0;
};
```

This is considered an interface.

And now I insert an enumerator (It can be something else, like a typedef, etc.)

```
class Numeric
{
public:
    enum Numbers
    {
        One,
        Two,
    };

    virtual Numbers getNumeric() const = 0;
};
```

Still being an interface or it is now considered an abstract class?

As I said, it might be silly but I really wonder to know that.

Comment: In essence, this is a distinction without a difference.  An interface is generally considered to have nothing about the implementation inside of it.  Whereas an abstract class is considered to be able to have implementation stuff in it.

Comment: Did you add the public member variable "numbers" on purpose?

Comment: @randomusername - When you say inside of it, you mean inside of the methods or the class itself? 'cause that is the reason of the question. The enumeration is declared inside of the class then if a class is considered abstract for declarations in class, then it becomes an abstract class. Am I right? - The opposite, it will be an interface.

Comment: @Horstling - Yes, this way the derived classes can use the enumeration.

Comment: @Almighty - Derived classes could use the enum (One, Two) without the member variable. Defining a public member here seems odd to me.

Comment: @Horstling - Yes, thank you, I got confused. I read your question and I thought that you were asking about the enumeration, but then I remembered that I defined the enumeration as "numbers". ;) - edited.

Comment: Technically, your first class is also not an interface since it has code (i.e. the virtual destructor ). An interface cannot have code. C++ does not have the concept of interfaces and you code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Chip: In C++ explicit "interfaces" get a little tricky, since a destructor is _required_ to have code.  And every class is required to have a destructor (though it may be implicit).  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb3b8aca666b64aa

Comment: @MooingDuck ya I know. That's why I said "technically" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an official answer, then I'm afraid there is none.

The draft of the C++11 standard I am having here merely says [10.4 class.abstract]:

> An abstract class can also be used to define an interface for which
>   derived classes provide a variety of implementations.

**All** other instances of the word *"interface"* in the entire ~1300 pages PDF only refer to generic programming or other things not related to OOP or abstract classes.

For example this one here [24.2.1 iterator.requirements.general]:

> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data
>   structures have interfaces that use ranges.

This obviously has nothing to do with abstract classes.

Bjarne Stroustrup himself, if you accept his words as "half-official", doesn't really help you in this regard, either. Quoting from the [glossary on his homepage](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html):

> abstract class - a class defining an interface only; used as a base
>   class.

You will have to live with the fact that the C++ language itself as well as C++ developers and experts use the word *"interface"* as a **superset** for *"abstract class"*. Unlike e.g. in Java, where interfaces are an actual language element with its own `interface` keyword, there is no such thing in C++.

Everything else is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Your second class `Numeric` is an interface.

If a class has one or more pure virtual functions, then this class is called an "abstract class".

Generally, if all of a classes' functions are pure virtual functions, then this class is called an "interface".

C++ does not have an explicit `interface` concept, so the above two classes are called the interface or abstract class, somewhat interchangably.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your second class can be considered an interface. I don't think there is a standard which defines interfaces in C++. However in languages which have interfaces, for example, Java, you can usually  have enums defined inside an interface.

I would consider a class with no implementation to be an interface.